# Product rule of stochastic exponents

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

we know that for standard exponents, $(e^x)(e^y)=e^{(x+y)}$. What is the product rule for stochastic exponents?

$E_n(U)E_n(V)=E_n(U+V+[U,V])$ where $U$ and $V$ are stocchastic sequences, $E_n$ is the stochastic exponent and $[U,V]_n$=$ \sum_{k=1}^n(\Delta_Uk*\Delta_Vk)$.

That is the rule, but whats the proof!? thx :)

Comment: What's the definition of $E$ you use?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "stochastic exponents", you mean stochastic exponentials, as in Doleans-Dade exponential semimartingales (at least, this definition is consistent with the product rule you mention). The proof of the property

$$
\mathcal{E}(X)\mathcal{E}(Y) = \mathcal{E}(X+Y+[X,Y])
$$

for semimartingales $X$ and $Y$ can be found as the proof of Theorem II.38 of P. Protter's book "Stochastic integration and Differential equations", 2nd edition.